# Array return in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello  i want to return array using php code it doesnot gives any output

Please take a look at code

```
<?php       
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
$a=array();

function showCombinations($string, $traits, $i)
{
    //print_r($i);
    if ($i >= count($traits)) {
        $a[]=trim($string) . "\n";
        return $a;
    } else {
        foreach ($traits[$i] as $trait) {
            //print_r($trait[$i]);
            showCombinations("$string $trait", $traits, $i + 1);
        }
    }
}

$traits = array
(
    array('Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry', 'Hopeful'),
    array('Outgoing', 'Introverted'),
    array('Tall', 'Short', 'Medium'),
    array('Handsome', 'Plain', 'Ugly')
);
//print_r($traits);exit;
echo showCombinations(' ', $traits, 0);
?>
```

Comment: what output you're expecting?

Comment: i want to return the same array as it prints in my if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) variable scope. Use `$GLOBALS[]`.

```
function showCombinations($string, $traits, $i)
  {         //print_r($i);
    if ($i >= count($traits))
    {
      $GLOBALS["a"][]=trim($string) . "\n";
      return $a;
    }
    else
    {
      foreach ($traits[$i] as $trait)
      //print_r($trait[$i]);
      showCombinations("$string $trait", $traits, $i + 1);  
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `else` part, you need to write:

```
return showCombinations("$string $trait", $traits, $i + 1);
```

your code then outputs:

```
Array
```

use `print_r` instead to see the contents of the array:

```
print_r(showCombinations(' ', $traits, 0));
```

outputs the following:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Happy Outgoing Tall Handsome
)
```